# How can I prevent word breaking into different lines in HTML Table?

Tags: html, css

[image: My Table]

My CSS includes
table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;
for table styling( I have large table which I have to fit in without Overflowing x)
I have used media query to overflow-x on smaller devices.
I have around 10 columns to be displayed, I just don't want words to break.
I've tried white-space, word-break properties but didn't worked

Comment: I guess this a problem regarding the width of your column compared to the size of your text. That's maybe not the cleanest solution but you should maybe reduce the font-size

Comment: `word-wrap: keep-all` will prevent linebreaks within a word but might cause overflow issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using below code works

```
word-break: normal;
word-wrap: normal;
overflow-wrap: normal;
-webkit-hyphens: normal;
-moz-hyphens: normal;
-ms-hyphens: normal;
hyphens: normal;
```

Another issue caused, I had zoom links in the cell which is lengthy which cannot be fitted inside so I used the below code for that particular cell

```
word-break: break-all;
```